# Deserialize a JSON String where there are no fixed KEY using vb

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization

I have extracted some data from a JSON Stream with one element being an array. The result of this is

```
"{" & vbCrLf & "  ""2019-08-22"": 128.75," & vbCrLf & "  ""2019-08-23"": 151.47," & vbCrLf & "  ""2019-08-24"": 151.47" & vbCrLf & "}"
```

I am then trying to separate the 3 values and place them into a database using VB.

Tried parse, deserialize but going round in circles.

```
Dim uObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse("{" & vbCrLf & "  ""2019-08-22"": 128.75," & vbCrLf & "  ""2019-08-23"": 151.47," & vbCrLf & "  ""2019-08-24"": 151.47" & vbCrLf & "}")
DEBUG.PRINT(uObject(1, 1)) - This fails
```

Trying to get the following output

```
Key1: 2019-08-22  Value1: 128.75
Key2: 2019-08-23  Value1: 151.47
Key3: 2019-08-24  Value1: 151.47
```

Comment: Deserialize the original JSON to a class structure. You'll have a List of objects with properties that you can then iterate and manipulate as you please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a quick test:

```
    Dim JSON_Obj As JObject = JObject.Parse("{" & vbCrLf & "  ""2019-08-22"": 128.75," & vbCrLf & "  ""2019-08-23"": 151.47," & vbCrLf & "  ""2019-08-24"": 151.47" & vbCrLf & "}")
    For Each item In JSON_Obj
        Debug.Print(String.Format("Key: {0} Value: {1}", item.key, item.value))
    Next
    '>Key: 2019-08-22 Value: 128.75
    '>Key: 2019-08-23 Value: 151.47
    '>Key: 2019-08-24 Value: 151.47
```

If you can't get it by key name, simply get them with array index or something, like JSON_Obj1 = JSON_Obj.Children.ToArray()(0)

Comment: CruleD - Thank you very much for this. For some reason For each item IN JSON_Obj would not work in VB but it got me well along the way and after a bit more digging around StackOverflow I found some variants.

Answer (score 0):

With great help from CruelD; my final working code is

```
        Dim JSON_Obj As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse("{" & vbCrLf & "  ""2019-08-22"": 128.75," & vbCrLf & "  ""2019-08-23"": 151.47," & vbCrLf & "  ""2019-08-24"": 151.47" & vbCrLf & "}")
        Dim JSON_Data As List(Of JToken) = JSON_Obj.Children().ToList
        For Each uItem As JProperty In JSON_Data
            Debug.Print(uItem.Name.ToString & " - " & uItem.Value.ToString)
        Next
```

This works a treat.

Comment: You don't need list if you are going to loop, but you could use it if you wanted to extract only one item.